# Efficient reading/writing of streams of bits in C++

Tags: c++, libraries

I'm writing a data compression library and I need to write a sequence of encodings of integers (in a variety of integer encoders) in memory, store it in a file and then read all of them later.

Integer encodings have to be stored consecutively. 
Since generally their size in bits isn't a multiple of 8, I don't have them aligned in memory.

In short, what I need is something which exposes functions like these:

```
unsigned int BitReader::read_bits(size_t bits);
unsigned int BitWriter::write_bits(unsigned int num, size_t bits);
void BitWriter::get_array(char** array);
BitReader::BitReader(char *array);
```

Since I need to invoke those functions in a (very) tight loop, efficiency is of paramount interest (especially in reading).

Do you know some C++ libraries which does what I want? Thanks.

Comment: It is efficient? It seems that BitSet implements a different abstraction with respect to what I need (they implement a *set*, I need a *stream*)

Comment: You can't read or write individual bits to disk, so your bitreader will have to do some buffering.

Comment: @Bo Persson: that's not a problem, I just want something that does all the stuff in memory and let me get the whole backing array, so I can write it in memory

Comment: I'd try it and see if it performs well. I cannot guess if bitset performance will be enough for your use case.

Comment: You've not defined what sort of "efficiency" you're looking for, but it looks like you're worried about raw performance. In which case I say: Stop right there! Write your code in the most obvious and maintainable manner, determine its performance, then profile and optimize those parts standing in the way of acceptable performance. (And I'll bet those parts will in no way be related to the problem you're thinking about here.) Google "premature optimization" and be enlightened.

Comment: I know what "premature optimisation" is, and it isn't certainly the case. I already know that I need to read bits from the "stream of bits" stored in memory as fast as possible, so I'm searching for something which is heavily tuned for modern processors (something which takes into account branch misprediction, allocating stuff in registers and things like that).

Comment: @akappa: I find it highly unlikely that you have developed a useful compression algorithm where the bottleneck is memory access and/or simple bit manipulation. I find it much more likely that you have failed to profile your code to determine the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: do you know what "gamma code" is? Do you know how many times you need to invoke those functions to read a SINGLE integer, and that a LZ77 phrase requires to read TWO integers? Do you know that Google's Snappy is optimized precisely to avoid as much as possible shifts and things like that? Please, I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @akappa: Wouldn't the bottleneck more likely be in disk I/O? Just playing devil's advocate here; please be gentle. :-)

Comment: @Emile: I'm sorry, but my question wasn't "how to optimize my compressor", but "there exists something that does this in a quick way?". I've presented a bit of context to just make the discussion about requirements a bit more solid. In my context (an academic one) I don't care at all about disk I/O (I can assume that the decompressed / compressed representation of my data is already in memory), I only care about lower-level memory hierarchy and CPU clocks spent in decoding values.

Comment: Boost is wayyy too big for just bit reading.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is your only requirement then get the address of the storage for the data and write it directly to storage. Then on restore allocate the same storage and perform the reverse operation. It's simple, fast, and has no learning curve.

Comment: I need to efficiently read sequentially individual bits from a stream of bits in memory, not storing and reading back the full stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Openning a stream to whatever input / output is the most affective although not efficient for huge amount of data. Streams provide a portable way of carrying out read/write operations thats why you can open stream in memory or disk. If you want to take control of the stream to the disk itself i would recommend using _bios_disk function google "_bios_disk" for more info.

Comment: It doesn't. I can't recall why I marked this as "accepted" but I don't agree anymore with whatever my thoughts were at that moment ;)